# Select Into Outfile Syntax Error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using UniController to run a localhost for my website. I'm trying to get information from my database and output it into a file with the following code from one of my php files. mysql_query($sql) is returning a value of FALSE. I'm not sure why and I need it to return TRUE.

```
$sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE \"".$file."\"
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \"\n\"
        FROM `cbmarker`.`cbdata`";

        if(sizeof($SQLArray) > 0)
        {
            $sql = $sql . " WHERE " . join(" AND ", $SQLArray) .";";
        }
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: What does `$sql` end up containing?

Comment: It will be something like this: SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "/var/www/tmp/dbdownload.csv" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY " " FROM `cbmarker`.`cbdata` WHERE `project_id`='155' AND `userid`='99' AND `review_mark`='0' ;